# ViewController Not Rotating

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

I have been having issues forever with an app, and getting certain views to rotate.

I already know that no view in a tab bar controller can rotate, unless ALL are allowed to rotate.  I also know that no view within a navigation controller can rotate unless the top most view is allowed to rotate.

I used IB mostly to setup my app.

In the `MainWindow.xib` I have the `AppDelegate Object`, `Window`, `TabBarController`, and then a separate `UIViewController`.

Within one of the tabs of the tab bar, I have an IBAction linked to a UIButton with the following code:

```
-(IBAction)stuff {
[self presentViewController:buletinss animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The view controller is declared in the header file as an `IBOutlet`, and is linked from that tab class to the `UIViewControlle`r.  In IB, I then set the class for that view controller to a `UIViewController` class I set up, and return `YES` to allow it to rotate.

However, it still will not rotate.

I thought that since it was not a part of the tab bar, and not pushed from a navigation controller, that it would be allowed to rotate, but I am having no luck.  Please any help?

### Here is full code:

First, the .h and .m for the view that has the button:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BulletinViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIWebView *worship;
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activity;
NSTimer *timer;
IBOutlet UIViewController *buletinss;

}
-(IBAction)stuff;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activity;

@end
```

and the .m

```
#import "BulletinViewController.h"

@implementation BulletinViewController

-(IBAction)stuff {

[self presentViewController:buletinss animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now the .h and the .m of the view it is presenting

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestBulletinViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

and the .m

```
#import "TestBulletinViewController.h"

@implementation TestBulletinViewController


-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation         {
return YES;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Give a full code for detect your error

Comment: @CReaTuS ok, see edits for the full code

Comment: What do you mean it won't rotate? Do you mean that you are holding the device in portrait but the presented view appears in landscape? Do you mean that the presented view appears and then you rotate the device and the view doesn't compensate? What?

Comment: @matt The 2nd one.  It loads in portrait (which is what I want), but when I rotate, the view does not compensate.

Comment: @user717452 What was the outcome on this?

Comment: Never got it to work properly.  Working on Auto-Layout stuff to see if it will help me do what I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this code

```
[self presentViewController:buletinss animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to

```
[self presentModalViewController:buletinss animated:YES];
```

**UPD:**  in iOS 6 you must:

**1)**

Replace

```
[window addSubview:buletinss.view];
```

with

```
window.rootViewController = buletinss;
```

**2)**

Add this code lines

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: Just the opposite; `presentModalViewController` will be deprecated eventually.

Comment: who is says? Where is a official link about this ?

Comment: Look for yourself. Read the header. I quote: "[`presentModalViewController`] has been replaced by `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. It will be DEPRECATED, plan accordingly." Advising someone to switch _to_ `presentModalViewController` is just wrong (and has no effect relevant to the question).

Comment: and now that iOS 6 is public I can "reveal" that `presentModalViewController` is in fact now officially deprecated. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html Always watch the headers, since this deprecation was clearly signalled well in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what's going on without seeing your project. You're doing a very odd thing: why are you loading a view controller from a nib? You are saying:

```
IBOutlet UIViewController *buletinss;
```

Why? Why are you not explicitly instantiating a BulletinViewController and setting the ivar to that?

I'm betting that the problem is that in the nib, this object is *not* a BulletinViewController. It's probably just a generic UIViewController. Hence your BulletinViewController code is irrelevant; none of it ever runs. Instead, you've got a generic UIViewController that only rotates to portrait. But that's just a guess.